# Trying To Set up a Yeoman Angular-Rails Environment

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, command, karma-runner, yeoman

I've been trying to set up an environment using this angular rails generator: https://github.com/sheniff/generator-angular-rails but it keeps failing when I run

```
Grunt test
```

It says that my karma unit is failing.

I'll post the log below

```
% grunt test
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning ".tmp"...OK

Running "coffee:dist" (coffee) task

Running "coffee:test" (coffee) task

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
directory .tmp/styles
WARNING: 'glyphicons-halflings.png' was not found (or cannot be read) in /Users//Desktop/ang-rails/app/images
WARNING: 'glyphicons-halflings-white.png' was not found (or cannot be read) in /Users/Desktop/ang-rails/app/images
    write .tmp/styles/main.css

Running "compass:server" (compass) task

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Started connect web server on localhost:9000.

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.32 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket 97z8INcxrnCo6SHwAAAA with id 66703306
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.001 secs / 0 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

---

I really don't think it's because my css is failing. When I run it with sudo I get

```
Warning: Task "compass:dist" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

npm 2.9.1
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5
bower 1.4.1
karma 0.12.32
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
ruby 2.2.1p85
phantomjs 2.0.0 (Something weird about this, when I run "phantomjs --version" it returns 2.0.0 but the error message above says phantomJS 1.9.8. So I'm trying to figure out why the distinction is there.

If it's something really obvious I'm missing my apologies, I've searched all over for a question similar to this one and been unable to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. In gruntfile.js the localhost was set to 9000 instead of 8080.